# Wordpress combine js, css and minified

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a question, about wordpress if i can combine all js on the site in a single js and all css from the page in one css. It's there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can gell *all* scripts/styles, but you can use `wp_dequeue_style` and 
`wp_dequeue_script` to remove some of the scripts/styles from wordpress that are added properly.

Then you would have to manually take those files and add them into a master file. Combining everything can be tricky though, be sure to make  note of the order everything was originally added in.

Alternativly, you could try the [JS & CSS Script Optimizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/js-css-script-optimizer/) plugin. Never used it myself.

Comment: Thank you for this plugin, it is allmost good, but i managed to modify for my good will. :P